# How to run Angular app as Docker container

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to run an Angular 9 app as a Docker container. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.8.0-stretch-slim as build-env
LABEL desc="docker image of angular 9 app"
WORKDIR /app
COPY ["package.json","package-lock.json","/app/"]
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

COPY . /app
#ENTRYPOINT ["ng","--version"]
RUN ng build
CMD ng serve 
#Also tried 1) CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 and 2) ENTRYPOINT ["ng","serve"]
```

It builds the image with few minor warnings and then builds the container

```
docker run -p 4203:4200 -d <image_id>
```

I can see the Docker container is running (VS Code Docker extension & `docker ps` command shows the container up). But when I try to access the app from browser, it shows the below error

[image]

How can I access my Angular app from browser?

Please note: I will be taking this forward by adding the second stage in the above Dockerfile and would host the app in some server but before doing that I want to make sure that app could be accessed.

Comment: Why not create the static build and serve it from any webserver (like nginx from docker) rather than `ng serve` ?

Comment: @miiiii, yes that I will do it a bit later. (if you see I have a stage build-env in my Dockerfile)

Comment: @miiiii How can I check that port? (docker inspect <image_id> is not showing any such info.

Comment: Can you follow steps of this article.. https://medium.com/better-programming/7-steps-to-dockerize-your-angular-9-app-with-nginx-915f0f5acac 
It's much like what you are doing and what you would want to doing future as well.

Comment: Unless you're trying to setup a Dockerised dev environment, you don't want to be running `ng serve` in the container. See e.g. https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats/blob/main/Dockerfile for a simple setup to build in Node then serve the result from Nginx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please  add this CMD instrcution to your dockerfile

```
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200
```

Comment: yes, it solved the issue. But Could you please add a bit of explanation? Thanks!

Comment: @Kgn-web by default ng serve listens only on localhost. If you want to access it from outside world(here it's your pc) you can use 0.0.0.0. which basically means listen to any ipv4 address.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this example. It's very similar that you'd like to do
Dockerfile (example):

```
FROM node:14

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli 

WORKDIR /frontend

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Terminal commands

Create the image

```
docker build -t <image name> .
```

Start the container (use the command "serve" and "--host" to append the "ng" command that was created in the Dockerfile):

```
docker run --rm -p 4200:4200 -it <image name>
```

Also, you may want add a volume in the container to map you local folders:

```
docker run --rm -v <absolute path to src file>:/<project path>/src -p 4200:4200 -it <image_name>
```

If you'd like to use ENTRYPOINT in the end of Dockerfile, use this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["ng"]
```

So, in the docker run command you have to append what you want to do:

```
docker run --rm -v <absolute path to src file>:/<project path>/src -p 4200:4200 -it <image_name> serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Or to create a component

```
docker run --rm -v <absolute path to src file>:/<project path>/src -p 4200:4200 -it <image_name> component <component name>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

You can try
0.0.0.0:4200 inside the docker file. That is how it worked for me.

Comment: I believe `EXPOSE` is just metadata, it isn't necessary or sufficient for actually exposing a port: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Comment: I changed the answer.